# Desktop disappeared after messing with ccsm

Tags: 11.10, unity, ccsm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I recently Installed ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop. yesterday I just run "compizConfig Settings manager" and just click on preferences tab, suddenly everything on the screen disappeared. Now the only thing I can see is the wallpaper.

None of the keys aren't responding other than "ctrl+alt+delete". I tried to run terminal by pressing "ctrl+alt+t" it doesn't work either. So I logged out and found this switch "Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D" on the welcome screen. I switched it to "Ubuntu 2D" and logged in, it worked, but it's not the same user interface I used earlier. So, Please tell me what has happened to my previous Ubuntu desktop, and is there any way I can fix it back to the default view ?